# Can I use AIC to compare across time period?

Tags: aic

1) I have some house prices from the year 1990. I have about 200 data points. Let us assume that I fit a best line and calculate the AIC score.

2) Now for the same houses (200 data points), I also have the price from the year 1991. Let us assume that I fit a best line again (with the same independent variable and the same dependent variable) and calculate the AIC score.

Can I compare the AIC scores of 1) and 2) if I use the same variables to model and I have exactly the same data points. The only thing is that the time period changes?

Comment: No, AIC/BIC assume same data are used in both models. Why wouldn't you try to fit both models with the same amount of data?

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there some other metric that allows me to compare the 'best' model across these two time periods? What I am trying to do is compare a statistical model with another statistical model (using the same set of variables). I like to know how do I find the 'best' model among the two.